# how to iterate all the column value using filters in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying extract user information from database. I have Signup database. If user already registered it will allow to login and i want to fetch login user all information from database and i want to store that information to variable.

Comment: Your question a bit unclear. Do you want to fetch from database all info about user when he is logged in?

Comment: The logged in user is `request.user` or `self.request.user` in a Django view. The `user` object has all the attributes, like `user.username`, `user.first_name`, etc. What do you need more? Show us your code and what you're trying to do so we can understand your issue.

Comment: @SergeyPugach Yes